# Python regular Expression to get text between two strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

when i read a text, i have string like `<h3 class="heading">General Purpose</h3>` in some of the lines of the text, now i want to get only value that is `General Purpose` from above..

```
d = re.search(re.escape('<h3 class="heading">')+"(.*?)"+re.escape('</h3>'), str(data2))
if d:
    print(d.group(0))
```

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? Include data2 in your question and also mention what are you trying to extract from data2.

Comment: Is this an example string, or do you actually have HTML? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I think you want d.group(1). 0 is the whole matched string, 1 is the first parenthesized group.

Comment: hey data2 is output of beautiful soup data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group 0 contains the entire match; you want the contents of group 1:

```
print(d.group(1))
```

But generally, using regexes to parse HTML is not such a good idea (although practically speaking, nested `h3` tags should be rather uncommon).

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

text="""<h3 class="heading">General Purpose</h3>"""
pattern="(<.*?>)(.*)(<.*?>)"

g=re.search(pattern,text)
g.group(2)
```

Output:

```
'General Purpose'
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tY2l2c/1)

If its a beautiful soup object then its even simpler to get the value. You wont need the regex.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text="""<h3 class="heading">General Purpose</h3>"""
a=BeautifulSoup(text)
print a.select('h3.heading')[0].text
```

Output:

```
General Purpose
```

Comment: If its already a beautifulsoup object then you don't have to use additional regex to extract the data. You can use beautifulsoup methods to extract the html data.

Comment: @kattaprasanth: I wrote my answer before your comment that you're using BeautifulSoup. In that case, please remove the "accepted" checkmark from my answer and give it to this one because it's clearly the better one.

Comment: @TimPietzcker .. Actually for that, beautifulsoup was returning None.. now its working i am using tbody to get the required output... thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Warning: works ONLY IN python, NOT pcre or JS (Lookbehind is not supported in JS).

```
(?<=\<\h3 class=\"heading\"\>).*?(?=\<\/h3\>)
```